# I/O operation on closed file error (Python2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, stdout

I need your help as a newbie.  I'm stuck in a problem while trying to rename the column in a txt file list.
Before renaming it, I remove the space

```
with open("smpl_list.txt", "r") as m, open ("smpl.txt","w") as n:
sys.stdout=n
for line in m:
    print line.strip()
```

After I import pandas to rename column

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("smpl.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["a","b","c","d"])
print (df)
```

But I constantly get "I/O operation on closed file" error. As I know, with block automatically close the file, but where is the problem, I really can not see at all.

**Edit:** Here is my worked code with contribution of @COLDSPEED

```
with open("smpl_list.txt", "r") as m, open ("smpl.txt","w") as n:
for line in m:
    n.write(line.strip()+"\n")
```

And the second part for renaming columns

```
import pandas as pd
with open ("smp.txt", "w") as r:
    df=pd.read_csv("smpl.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["a","b","c","d"])
    print>> r, df
```

The final result of the list with out left space(there were before) and with column name

[image]

Comment: Please fix your indentation first before asking what's wrong with your code.

Comment: It was already indented properly in the script, but so sorry when I paste it, the indentations disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `sys.stdout` to do redirection with print is the *wrong* way to go about it, because you'll cause irreversible damage.

The problem happens because you reassign it to a file pointer within the context manager. After exiting the `with` block, the manager automatically closes, so `sys.stdout` points to a closed file, which is why you get that error.

You have 2 options. The first option is to fix the issue by reloading `sys`. You can do that with

```
import imp
imp.reload(sys)
```

The second, and better option (which I prefer) is to not get into this situation at all. Python2's print statement has a syntax that allows you to redirect without having to jump through hoops:

```
with open("smpl_list.txt", "r") as m, open ("smpl.txt","w") as n:
    for line in m:
        print >> n, line.strip()
```

Or, slightly better:

```
with open("smpl_list.txt", "r") as m, open ("smpl.txt","w") as n:
    for line in m:
        n.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Comment: Sorry of course.  I should have said `n.write(line)` is more efficient.  And it is .  :)  I apologize for the mixup.

Comment: @ COLDSPEED Thank you for your good point on sys.stdout and print >> n, line.strip() is such an awesome solution for me. Many thanks

Comment: @Z.Grey Glad I could help!